# Insert timestamp in MySQL using Java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to insert a record to MySQL table using Java. My table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE records (
id int(5) NOT NULL,
value varchar(30) NOT NULL,
recorded_time timestamp(3) NOT NULL 
);
```

My code to insert record in MySQL:

```
for (Record rec : records) {
    st.setInt(1, rec.getId());
    st.setString(2, rec.getValue().toString());

    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(rec.getDatetime());
    System.out.println("New Timestamp: " + ts);

    st.setTimestamp(3, ts);

    System.out.println("Insert Statement: " + st);
    st.addBatch();
}
st.executeBatch();
```

where `st` is the preparedstatement. Output:

```
New Timestamp: 2017-09-18 17:59:03.362
Insert statement: INSERT INTO records ( id, value, recorded_time ) VALUES (306,'72.7','2017-09-18 17:59:03')
```

Value of 'datetime' field is generated using ZonedDateTime in Java8:

```
ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

My question is timestamp shows the millisecs when I print it. But why the  millisecs (362) not stored in the table. How to fix it.

Similar question on stackoverflow: [How to insert current time in MySQL using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534775/how-to-insert-current-time-in-mysql-using-java). But I don't know how to use it in my case.

EDIT: MySQL version - 10.1.6

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299149/timestamp-with-a-millisecond-precision-how-to-save-them-in-mysql can answer your question.

Comment: MySQL version is 10.1.6. Should I still multiply with .001?

Comment: How do you know that the milliseconds are not stored in the table? What query are you using for checking that?

Comment: I checked in the table by using `SELECT` statement.
 306 | 72.7 | 2017-09-18 17:59:03.000

Comment: @HaifengZhang: Yes, I thought so. But I don't know how to fix it. Any suggestions?

Comment: `Insert statement: INSERT INTO records ( id, value, recorded_time ) VALUES (306,'72.7','2017-09-18 17:59:03')` the fractions were truncated before you insert into database. check your setTimestamp() mehtod

Comment: @user2782405 this was reported as a bug https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=40279  The nano fractions were truncated when setTimestamp().  One solution is you set it to varchar/string instead, then keep the full precision.

Comment: I checked the link before posting. Since the thread was last updated in 2015, I thought it would have been fixed by now. I had no idea about it. Thank you @HaifengZhang